# Recommended method signature when returning output from asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, async-await, async-ctp

I have one asynchronous method:

```
public async Task<BitmapSource> GetBitmapAsync(double[] pixels);
```

Let's say I also have this class:

```
public class PixelData
{
    public double[] Pixels { get; }
}
```

I now want to create a convenience method producing a `BitmapSource` output, using the asynchronous method above to do the work. I can come up with at least three approaches to do this, but it is not immediately obvious to me which one I should choose from an efficiency and reliability point of view.

Can someone advice; what are the advantages and drawbacks of each one of the following approaches?

***Option A*** Create a synchronous method that returns the `Result` of the `Task`:

```
public BitmapSource GetBitmap(PixelData pixelData)
{
    return GetBitmapAsync(pixelData.Pixels).Result;
}
```

***Option B*** Create a synchronous (or is it asynchronous?) method that returns `Task<BitmapSource>`:

```
public Task<BitmapSource> GetBitmap(PixelData pixelData)
{
    return GetBitmapAsync(pixelData.Pixels);
}
```

***Option C*** Create an asynchronous method that explicitly uses `await`:

```
public async Task<BitmapSource> GetBitmapAsync(PixelData pixelData)
{
    return await GetBitmapAsync(pixelData.Pixels);
}
```

Comment: And you want to be able to call this convenience method asynchronously also? If so, from what I can see on the face of it the first two options won't achieve this, only the third will.

Comment: Not necessarily (do I want to call the convenience method asynchronously), but if that is the most reliable/correct way to do it, then yes.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Sorry for my ignorance in this matter, but will Option B be handled as a synchronous method _for certain_? The fact that it returns a `Task<BitmapSource>`, is that irrelevant with respect to (a)synchronicity?

Comment: Actually I'm not entirely sure myself, you might be able to call it with `await` - though I haven't got VS2012 in front of me to double check.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson, It will not run synchronously.

Comment: Thanks, @FilipEkberg. I just checked myself and realized that I have to `await` for Option B. It is thus asynchronous, even if it is not evident from the method signature.

Comment: Methods are not awaitable. [Only *types* are awaitable](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), so you can `await` a `Task` regardless of whether it's returned from an `async` or non-`async` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking this.

You've got a method that returns a type that happens to be a `Task<T>`. You want a method that takes a different type of parameter and passes through to the original method. So Option B is fine:

```
public Task<BitmapSource> GetBitmap(PixelData pixelData)
{
    return GetBitmapAsync(pixelData.Pixels);
}
```

The method should be called `GetBitmapAsync` though.

Option A would be the way to expose a synchronous ( blocking ) version of the method.

Option C doesn't actually achieve anything more than Option B.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas! Is it even so that Option C is _worse_ than Option B, in that it would add redundant asynchronous handling? Or are the two options equivalent internally?

Comment: Also, Option A [can cause deadlocks](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Stephen Toub has a [good video on async performance](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T), and he points out that Option C is not a good idea (for overhead reasons).